# Question on H bridge motor circuit

Tags: voltage, mosfet, capacitor, motor, h-bridge

I just finished task 1 on my project but my teacher has not provided any good guidelines so I was just hoping if you guys could check my work before I move on to step 2 and let me know if I'm correct or wrong as i don't want to dive into step 2 without knowing if my step 1 is correct. Below i will attach my task sheet.

[image: Task sheet]

Below I will attach the motor circuit that i have built
[image: Motor circuit]

Below i will upload my result. The first result is the voltage vs time of V1
[image: V vs time for V1]

Below i will upload my set of results for my current vs time for D2, V3, R1
[image: Current vs time for D2 V3 R1]

Finally i will upload my error log.
[image]

Comment: parts of your schematic are horrible ... there should not be any unnecessary zig-zags in lines (your schematic has quite a few) ... if your schematic was cleanly drawn then it is possible that you would have noticed an unintentional short circuit

Comment: I would say Step 1 is totally incomplete. You must include specs for all measurable parameters and limits to verify on the design later.  Schematic is too non-std. and ugly, missing pullups PWM , BoostV etc etc   look up ESC design https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtfwC.png